# Android Video Upload without wait for Response

Tags: android

I have created the video upload activity with AsyncTask function. I tried to send request to sever for upload the video , server take more time to upload and return response . Is there anyway to send response to server without wait for server response ? Just I need to send request to server, no need to wait for repsonse and transfer to other page's .

Kindly explain how to do .

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

No need to wait for the response , don't start the activity (transfer to other pages) inside onPostExecute method.

if you post your code I can help you more.

**Edit**:

I don't know if you really want to do this , how user will know that the video was uploaded successfully , any way you can do that by moving the start activity code from the (onPostExecute) , you can put it in  (onPreExecute) , or after calling (uploadVideo) as below:

```
private String videourl;
private TextView statusView;
ProgressDialog uploading;
private String questionid;
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 4500;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}



statusView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uploadstatus);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    if (extras.containsKey("path")) {
        videourl = extras.getString("path");
        questionid = String.valueOf(extras.getInt("questionID"));
    }


}
uploading = ProgressDialog.show(UploadActivity.this, "Uploading File",     "Please wait...", false, false);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        uploadVideo();
// add the start activity code here
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewQuestions.class);
                //  Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawingActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("questionID", questionid);

                startActivity(in);

                finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
private void uploadVideo() {
class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        uploading.dismiss();


        Log.i("Video Response", s.toString());
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            if(jsonObject.has("validation")){

                if(jsonObject.getString("validation") == "true" ){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Video Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Video not created ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
//remove start activity call from here
              /*  Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewQuestions.class);
                //  Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawingActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("questionID", questionid);
                finish();
                startActivity(in);*/
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Upload u = new Upload();
        String msg = u.uploadVideo(videourl,questionid,UploadActivity.this);
        return msg;
    }
}
UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo();
uv.execute();
}
```

But also I think you should use Services  instead of AsyncTask to make sure that the upload will be completed as the AsyncTask maybe killed after the activity is finished, try [this](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service) service for file upload .

**Note:**

you should add your the code in the question not as answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply .

Answer (score 0):

public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String videourl;
private TextView statusView;
ProgressDialog uploading;
private String questionid;
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 4500;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }



    statusView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uploadstatus);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.containsKey("path")) {
            videourl = extras.getString("path");
            questionid = String.valueOf(extras.getInt("questionID"));
        }


    }
    uploading = ProgressDialog.show(UploadActivity.this, "Uploading File", "Please wait...", false, false);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            uploadVideo();

        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
private void uploadVideo() {
    class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            uploading.dismiss();


            Log.i("Video Response", s.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                if(jsonObject.has("validation")){

                    if(jsonObject.getString("validation") == "true" ){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Video Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Video not created ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewQuestions.class);
                    //  Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawingActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("questionID", questionid);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Upload u = new Upload();
            String msg = u.uploadVideo(videourl,questionid,UploadActivity.this);
            return msg;
        }
    }
    UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo();
    uv.execute();
}
```

}

Please check and let me know changes. 
Thank you .